# About driver rotation Degree and Radian

Tags: scripting, rigging

I tried to add driver to Sphere's RotateX and link it with Cube's LocationX.

However, as shown in the image below, the driver value is 4.651, but the Sphere RotateY is 266.

[image]

The value of the driver will be regarded as radians without permission.

I created and tried the following Expression and it worked correctly, is this method recommended by Blender?

```
var * (3.1415/180)
```

Comment: I don't know why it uses radians here, as it displays degrees, I guess underneath the units system it uses radians and this must be what drivers act on.  It is quite annoying and unintuitive.

Comment: @Merlin scene > units > rotation is set to display degrees by default. (Which makes perfect sense, since multiples / fractions  of 360 is easier to visualize than those of pi)    The standard python math module is available to drivers.  Using `sin(value)`  will give the expected result  with a radian input value. Same with `numpy`.   No guessing needed, blender uses radians under the hood.  Once this is known it's really not that difficult.

Comment: @batFINGER thanks, I don't have a problem with radians per se but with entering a value as a driver doesn't honour the units. If for example I enter a driver with #frame / 360, one would expect it to revolve at 1 degree per frame but it doesn't, in fact tests show it as deciframes per radian or something weird.  I understand the technical challenge that it presents, but intuition would observe that units should be in the chosen system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's correct that the value is in radians. Blender uses radians for angles internally, since this is common practice for the calculation of trigonometric functions. The conversion to degree is only for display purposes in the user interface.

The same situation can be seen in the Python API. Assuming that you have an object named 'Cube' in your scene which is rotated 180° around the x-axis. When accessing the Euler rotation

```
bpy.data.objects["Cube"].rotation_euler.x
```

you will see that it returns `3.1415927410125732` which is a rough approximation of $\pi$.

This was previously asked on the bug tracker in [T29797](https://developer.blender.org/T29797).

Comment: Maybe a mention or picture of scene > units > rotation

Comment: The displayed unit for the angles can be changed in *Scene Properties > Units* as shown in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPtaK.png). However since this impact how the driver handles the value, I don't think this is really relevant.

Comment: Since the math module is loaded for the driver expression (when Python restrictions are disabled) you can also use `radians(var)` if you want `var` to be treated as angle in degree and convert it to radians.

Comment: '...rough approximation...'  :)

Comment: The unit can be changed\?   Good to know. , The assumption to this question is that the values should match.  if the unit is set to radians the values do ofcourse match,  Matching expectation. Suggested as  a visual aid re  first paragraph above.

Comment: @batFINGER They can't be changed for driver as far as I'm aware. The unit settings are only for the UI. Edit: Oh I see, my comment is missing a "doesn't".