# How do you convert a rotation to use as a value between 0 and 1?

Tags: constraints, drivers

Basically I have a bone that rotates, and I want to use it's rotation to drive an Influence of another bone that ranges between 0 and 1...

For example:

If the bone rotates 0 degrees, the value is 0.0
If the bone rotates 45 degrees, the value is 0.5
If the bone rotates 90+ degrees, the value is 1.0

How can I achieve this with drivers / constraints?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What happens if the bone is 180 or -90 degrees?

Answer (score 4):

As the rotations are calculated in radians (degrees are shown only as helper), the correct driver formula to get 0.0 - 1.0 range from 0 to 90 degrees is: 2*var/pi.

[image]

Check theese answers for more infos.
[About driver rotation Degree and Radian](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159557/about-driver-rotation-degree-and-radian)